What is best practice when escaping the_title()?
I have a custom theme. I want to output the post title of my post. I have achieved this already by using <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>. However, some say this is not escaped. In fact, I can run JS such as <script>alert("test");</script> if I place that in the post title. I have tried (1) <?php esc_html(the_title('<h1>','</h1>'))?>  but it runs the aforementioned JS as well and does not output any HTML. Also tried (2) <h1><?php echo esc_html(the_title);</h1> with the same result as (1).
Happy New Year! /dfr

You would use it like this:
<?php the_title(); ?>


In fact, I can run JS such as alert("test"); if I place that in the post title.

This is because you are either a super admin on a multisite or an administrator role on a non-multisite, these gain the unfiltered_html bypassing all sanitising on save. This is why you can put raw script tags in posts, other users cannot, and this capability is disabled on a lot of enterprise hosts as it's a security concern.
Having said that, it has nothing to do with escaping, your title could contain script tags, and escaping would still print them, but the tags would be escaped and they would be visible to people reading them on the frontend rather than executed/seen as actual tags.
So instead:

Use the_title() as is, to directly output the title
Or, if you're concerned that the user has the unfiltered_html capability, use echo esc_html( get_the_title(

Note though that the title is used in many other places though such as OEmbed and SEO tags, as well as the title tag, it may be easier to eliminate the unfiltered_html capability, and I recommend you do this if only as a security measure.

I have tried (1) <?php esc_html(the_title('<h1>','</h1>'))?>

This failed for multiple reasons that have nothing to do with WordPress but highlight missing information about PHP basics

There's no echo! So if it worked it wouldn't print anything
the_title does not return a value by default, it outputs directly

This means that the code is the same as this:
echo esc_html('');
the_title('<h1>','</h1>');


Also tried (2) <h1><?php echo esc_html(the_title);</h1> with the same result

This is better as it includes an echo but you've asked it to escape the function itself, not the posts title, this is almost equivalent to this:
echo esc_html( function the_title() { .... } );

Which will likely result in a PHP warning like this:
Warning: Uncaught Error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in...

Important things to note for the future:

Check first but a general rule of thumb is that the_... will output directly without an echo, and get_the or get_ requires an echo statement and an escaping function.
Functions beginning with the_ tend to do their own escaping internally
Don't double escape! esc_html( esc_html( is very bad and can let stuff leak through if it's crafted right
calling a function involves () somewhere, you can't apply escaping like a modifier or buff by calling escape(function_name)
escape as late as you possibly can, ideally at the moment of output
avoid gathering HTML bits in a variable then printing it at the end, it makes it super super hard to escape stuff properly
don't escape input, that's what sanitising and validating are for, escaping is only for output
Do not try to use esc_js and esc_sql they don't do what they appear to do and have very specific internal uses. wpdb->prepare should cover all SQL related escaping, and wp_json_encode can prepare data for javascript so you don't have to construct it out of strings when showing the page

